# unexpected binary tree result

Tags: c++, binary-tree, c++builder

```
struct BSTreeNode
{
    struct BSTreeNode *leftchild;  
        AnsiString data;  
    struct BSTreeNode *rightchild;  
};

struct BSTreeNode * root;  

String tree = "";

struct BSTreeNode * newNode(AnsiString x)  
{
    struct BSTreeNode * node = new struct BSTreeNode;
    node->data = x; 
    node->leftchild = NULL;  
    node->rightchild = NULL;  
    return node;
}

struct BSTreeNode * insertBSTree(struct BSTreeNode * node , AnsiString x)  
{   if(node == NULL) return newNode(x);
    if(x < node->data)
        node->leftchild = insertBSTree(node->leftchild, x);
    else
        node->rightchild = insertBSTree(node->rightchild, x);
    return node;
}

void printBSTree(struct BSTreeNode * node) 
{   if(node != NULL)
    {   printBSTree(node->leftchild);
        tree += node->data+"_";
        printBSTree(node->rightchild);
    }
}

//--- insert button ---
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    AnsiString data;
    data = Edit1->Text;
    root = insertBSTree(root, data);
    tree = "";
    printBSTree(root);
    Memo1->Lines->Add(tree);
}
```

Supposed that I insert A、B、C、D、E、F、G into the binary tree(Button1Click is the button to insert data into the binary tree)
the binary tree should be like

```
      A
    /   \
   B     C
  / \   / \    
 H  J   D  E
       / \
      F   G
```

but it turned out to be like

```
 A   
  \    
   B
    \
     C
      \
       D
        \
         E
          \
           F
            \ 
             G
```

struct BSTreeNode ---> tree node

struct BSTreeNode * newNode(AnsiString x) ---> creating a new node

button1Click ---> insert the data from Edit->text; to the binary tree.

insertBSTree ---> if the node is null, then create a new node. Inserting the data into the leftchild/rightchild

Comment: In C++, it is useless to use `struct` keyword when specifying a type. `BSTreeNode` is already a type, don't write `struct BSTreeNode` everywhere.

Comment: @prapin: one would also suggest using references or making these functions member functions.

Comment: Please post a *minimal* example of the problem (looks like just A & B will suffice), and what you did to try and diagnose the problem (i.e. use a debugger to see where it first didn't do what you expected).

Comment: What are the `data` values in your example?

Comment: Code looks OK, what's not clear is why you are expecting the result you are expecting. That is not a valid binary search tree for the data shown.

Comment: I debugged and there's no bugs.
"data" stores the value of the binary tree. For exmaple, if I insert "A" into the binary tree(Button1Click), the value "A" will be stored into "data".
My teacher's assisant told me that my binary tree turned out to be like the second one in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a binary search tree when you use `<` to determine which branch to insert into:

> ```
> struct BSTreeNode * insertBSTree(struct BSTreeNode * node , AnsiString x)  
> {   if(node == NULL) return newNode(x);
>     if(x < node->data)
>         node->leftchild = insertBSTree(node->leftchild, x);
>     else
>         node->rightchild = insertBSTree(node->rightchild, x);
>     return node;
> }
> ```

Your second example *is* a binary search tree, just not a *balanced* one.

Your expected result cannot be created by the functions shown because they maintain a strict invariant where the left branch must only contain values less than the root. The efficiency involved in a binary search tree only applies to balanced ones.

A balanced binary search tree containing this data would look like the following, because *all* trees involved (including subtrees) are balanced.

```
       D
      / \
     /   \
    /     \
   B       F    
  / \     / \
 A   C   E   G
```

You can get to this by adding a mechanism to check if your tree is balanced, and making adjustments by "rotating" trees left or right.

```
A
 \
  B
   \
    C
```

Becomes balanced, by rotating left around the smallest value on the right side of the tree.

```
   B
  / \
 A   C
```

To balance your initial tree:

```
 A   
  \    
   B
    \
     C
      \
       D
        \
         E
          \
           F
            \ 
             G
```

You'd check each subtree to see if it's balanced. The first subtree that is unbalanced is E, F, G.

```
 A   
  \    
   B
    \
     C
      \
       D
        \
         F
        / \
       E   G
```

We'd then see that D, E, F, G is unbalanced to the right.

```
 A   
  \    
   B
    \
     C
      \
       E
      / \
     D   F
          \
           G
```

And so on...

```
 A   
  \    
   B
    \
     D
    / \
   C   E
        \
         F
          \
           G
```

```
 A   
  \    
   B
    \
     D
    / \
   C   F
      / \
     E   G
```

```
 A   
  \    
   C
  / \
 B   D
      \
       F
      / \
     E   G
```

```
 A   
  \    
   C
  / \
 B   E
    / \
   D   F
        \
         G
```

```
  A   
   \    
    D
   / \
  C   E
 /     \
B       F
         \
          G
```

```
  A   
   \    
    D
   / \
  C   F
 /   / \
B   E   G
```

```
    B   
   / \    
  A   C
       \
        D
         \
          F
         / \
        E   G
```

```
    B   
   / \    
  A   C
       \
        E
       / \
      D   F
           \
            G
```

```
    B   
   / \    
  A   D
     / \
    C   E
         \
          F
           \
            G
```

```
    B   
   / \    
  A   D
     / \
    C   F
       / \
      E   G
```

```
    C   
   / \    
  B   D
 /     \
A       F
       / \
      E   G
```

```
    C   
   / \    
  B   E
 /   / \
A   D   F
         \
          G
```

If we go another few steps further:

```
      D   
     / \    
    C   E
   /     \
  B       F
 /         \
A           G
```

```
      D   
     / \    
    B   E
   / \   \
  A   C   F
           \
            G
```

```
       D
      / \
     /   \
    /     \
   B       F    
  / \     / \
 A   C   E   G
```